# any way to use linux command file recursively?

Tags: linux, file, terminal

I use this really useful command :

```
 file *
```

to get quality/identity of listed files.

But I'd like to list recursively, from a given folder.
In another words, doing something like that :
(command below does not exist)

```
 file * -r
```

Any trick to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` for that, using the `-exec` switch:

```
find ./ -type f -exec file {} \;
```

Small explanation:

```
{} : result of the "find" command, used as an input for the "file" command
\; : terminator of the "find ... -exec ..." command
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use xargs(1):

```
find . | xargs file
```

Sample output:

```
./.config/xfe:                 directory
./.config/xfe/xfirc:           ASCII text
./.Xauthority:                 X11 Xauthority data
./line/serialLG1800.py:        Python script, ...
```

If file names contain spaces or other special characters, it is best to use the -print0 option for find and, doing so, also must add -0 option for xargs:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

Comment: I personally don't like `xargs` that much: normally a command is launched as "command parameter" (first the command and then the parameter). Using `find .. -exec ...` this is exactly what happens: `find ... -exec command {} \;` (first the command and then the parameter, in this case being the `find` result, shown as `{}`). `xargs` does just the opposite: `xargs file` which means `parameter command`, which is the inverse of the normal order.

Comment: @Dominique you are true, the *-exec* find option is more consistent and fast, especially in this case. I wanted simply fill the picture. Sometimes (when?), it seems, xargs can be better or do more.

Comment: [There's an interesting AskUbuntu question about that subject](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959024/what-is-the-difference-between-find-with-exec-and-xargs)

Comment: Ty @Dominique, it was interesting.